# PCR to prevent TPM2 key unsealing in case of rogue DMA devices connected?

Tags: disk-encryption, tpm, luks, physical-access, dma-attack

Security threat: physical theft of a laptop and a server that use TPM2 auto unlock FDE with LUKS. In both cases the TPM checks against some PCRs before unsealing the key. The laptop prompts for a TPM PIN, the server doesn't. The attacker is in possession of a DMA device that can read the encryption key from RAM or CPU memory (e.g. Tresor-Hunt).

From what I understood to mitigate DMA attacks, IOMMU is not trivial to implement and does not protect at very early boot stages, such as TPM unlock of an encrypted partition. PCRs instead are checked early by the TPM to decide if the encryption key should be unsealed.

While a TPM PIN may be prompted to the user to unseal the key of a FDE laptop (similar to what happens after a full reboot of an iOS or Android device), it may be less convenient for a server that should boot automatically in case of a power outage.

If a malicious actor in possession of a DMA attack device steals such a laptop, he would still need to provide the PIN to make the TPM unseal the key that he wants to sniff, so I assume the laptop is fine (is it?).

However, if he steals the server, he could just plug in the rogue DMA peripheral and sniff the automatically unsealed key, as the TPM does not check for rogue devices attached.

Is there a way to make the TPM not unseal the key by checking a PCR if new (rogue) devices are connected? E.g. if I had 0 PCI-e cards when I enrolled the TPM, I don't want it to boot if there is one attached.

Supposing yes, how can the server be protected from those devices if they are attached after the boot process?